# Is it possible to change the app icon while the App is running

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, appicon

Not really an important question but was just curious. Can you change the app icon while running. For example, there is a button, and when you press the button, you get a different app icon (given that the app icons are already 'set') in flutter. Android and iOS.

Any input is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 10.3, developers are able to programmatically change the app icon.

For details,You may can refer to this [link](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/dynamically-change-the-app-icon-7d4bece820d2), it shows how to dynamically change the app icon.

Sample code:

```
// change app icon to "Picture A"
@IBAction func pichuButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  changeIcon(to: "Picture A")
}

// change app icon to "Picture B"
@IBAction func pikachuButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  changeIcon(to: "Picture B")
}

// change app icon to "Picture C"
@IBAction func raichuButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  changeIcon(to: "Picture C")
}
func changeIcon(to iconName: String) {
  // 1
  guard UIApplication.shared.supportsAlternateIcons else {
    return
  }

  // 2
  UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(iconName, completionHandler: { (error) in
    // 3
    if let error = error {
      print("App icon failed to change due to \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
      print("App icon changed successfully")
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the manifest or the resource in the signed-and-sealed APK, except through a software upgrade.